# nginx php mysql multiple site

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

i have trouble configuring Nginx/php to route service requests to different sites. We have created a service within our web app that pushes content to nginx hosted web site (actually the service cals on the web server php script which writes the content to the database and nginx is presenting it on the website using php). All is working fine with the root web site (Site A). The request is received and written to MySql database to database A and website is reading it fine. Problem is with site B, every request sent to site B is received by site A and written to database A instead to database B.

I have tried with php-fpm separating them but with no luck. My experience with nginx/php configuration is low so any help would be apreciated. What kind of setup is needed to achieve this.

What i have tried so far.

Created a new pool in php pool.d folder. siteB.conf, its content is.

```
; Start a new pool named 'www'. 
; the variable $pool can be used in any directive and will be replaced by the 
; pool name ('www' here) [siteB]
user = www-data group = www-data
listen = /run/php/php7.0-fpm-siteB.sock
listen.owner = www-data 
listen.group = www-data
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
```

? do i need sock value/port, does user/group needs to be changed from www-group to another user.

Within folder `var/www/html/php/service` there is a php script which connects to the mysql database and writes the content for the first web site (site A).

On the nginx sever i have several web sites (all accessed through port 80)and each web site has its own database file within the mysql database. all other sites have same setup ( for example `var/www/siteB/php/service`)

When pointing to an ip adress `http:/siteA/php/service` all works well, the content is written to the appropriate database.

when pointing to an address `http://siteB/php/service` the content is not written. Serving the web site pages works well from nginx, all websites load except for the DB content (which was not writen to the DB file.).

So i am guessing that i need to configure nginx to properly route the request to siteB, how can i do this.

My nginx configuration is

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
worker_connections 768;
# multi_accept on;
}

http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;

 server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# SSL Settings
##

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

# gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript 
text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Comment: Please show your nginx configuration.

Comment: I agree, you need to show the relevant parts of your nginx configuration.

Comment: updated the question with nginx config file